# Assert.AreEqual failed. Expected:<‭8‬>. Actual:<8> when ran my Coded UI test method

Tags: c#, csv, coded-ui-tests

In my codedui test method I am comparing the output value with my csv file. Basically I am using calculator application and selecting the programmer mode option. Clicking one button (here clicked button 8) and comparing the output as Decimal,HexaDecimal,Binary and Octal value with my result (i.e.from my csv file). While comparing the result , I used `Assert.AreEqual()` method.
Below is my code snippet:

```
try
{
    Assert.AreEqual(TestContext.DataRow["Binary"].ToString().Split(' ')[1].Trim(), control.ToString().Split(' ')[1].Trim(), "Binary value matches with expected.");
}
catch (AssertFailedException err)
{
    Console.WriteLine(err.Message);
}
```

However when I ran the testmethod, my test passed and show below message:

> Assert.AreEqual failed. Expected:<‭1000‬>. Actual:<1000>.

I am not sure why Asser.AreEqual failed.

Comment: Are there any non-printing chars in either value? Set a breakpoint on the assert-line, debug the test and check both values...

Comment: Thank Johan, I put a breakpoint and found that Assert.AreEqual only performing the Object verification. Referred https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms243486.aspx and helps me to resolve the issue which i faced.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue resolved by changing my Assert.AreEqual(expected,actual, string) (where expected and actual value are string to  Assert.AreEqual(string,string,boolean,string) overloadlist which Verifies that two specified strings are equal, ignoring case or not as specified. The assertion fails if they are not equal. Displays a message if the assertion fails.

I changed my code to as below:

```
try
{
    Assert.AreEqual(TestContext.DataRow["Binary"].ToString().Split(' ')[1].Trim(), control.ToString().Split(' ')[1].Trim(),true, "Actual Binary value does not match with expected.");
}
catch (AssertFailedException err)
{
    Console.WriteLine(err.Message);
}
```

When I ran my test method it works. I referred below msdn site for further clarification:
[Assert.AreEqual Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.assert.areequal.aspx)
and [Assert.AreEqual Method (String, String, Boolean, String)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms243486.aspx)

Comment: Just to make the answer more obvious. would you mind starting it with calling out to use the ignore case option of `Assert.AreEqual` for string comparisons?